# jqgrid treegrid, howto drag and drop rows?

Tags: jqgrid, drag-and-drop, treegrid, free-jqgrid

I have a jqgrid treegrid (v4.8 free). I implemented full management (add, edit and delete) for nodes.

```
 $("#tree").jqGrid({
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:400/hamed",
            datatype: "json",
            colNames: ['id', 'Name', 'Link', ''],
            colModel: [ .....
```

I want move up or move down a node and children. So that all children of node, and node move. (drag and drop or move buttons)
How to code my treegrid?

Comment: no distractions, no chit-chat (read [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)). Thanks should never be part of a good question.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately free jqGrid don't provide you any additional features which could simplify the implementation drag and drop of nodes of TreeGrid. You will have to call `getNodeChildren` recursively to get all children of the node. You can use standard `jQuery.after`, `jQuery.before`, `jQuery.insertAfter` or `jQuery.insertBefore` to move the nodes on the other place. jqGrid have currently no methods which could simplify the implementation.